# Is it possible to make images in srcset code clickable?

Tags: html, css

Site: www.legalteklx.com I have some images in a slider on my home page. The images are in srcset code for the purposes of responsive queries. I would like to make the sliding images clickable, but don't know if this is possible or how I would add links to the code as it is.

```html
<div class="slide active">
  <div class="container">
    <strong class="title"><strong><em>LX</em>&thinsp;Monarch</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;High Definition&hellip;Single Touch Control<span>Powerful Simplicity&hellip;</span></strong>
    <a href="LXMonarch_ProductPage.php" class="btn">Learn More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-stretch">
    <span data-srcset="images/prod02-sm.jpg, images/prod02-sm@2x.jpg 2x"></span>
    <span data-srcset="images/prod02.jpg, images/prod02@2x.jpg 2x" data-media="(min-width: 768px)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clickable"? What do you want to happen when they're clicked?

Comment: The code you have shown does not even contain any actual image elements. There is probably some additional JS that transforms this into something else.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. this code: <span data-srcset="images/prod02-sm.jpg, images/prod02-sm@2x.jpg 2x"> shows two images. (a small & large version of the same image) this is one of 3 images that fill the whole front page slider. I want to click on the image anywhere while it is displayed and be taken to an interior page of the site.

Answer (score 0):

in order to make any element clickable, a common method is to apply
`<a></a>` label to wrap the element and make it as a link so that the element will become clickable.

Comment: I understand that is the typical way to do it, (with <a href=....></a>) but the existing code with the srcset seems to make it problematic I tried adding the code but nothing happens)

Comment: I checked the documentation, it seems that if you want to use the srcset attribute, you would use a ```<img>``` label with a src and alt attribute instead of use ```<span>```. See this:[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) "

Comment: Besides, I tried use the ```<a>``` to wrap the responsive images on my computer, it works without problem.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Can you show me the html you wrote to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="slider container">
    <ul class="pictures">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="images/pic1.jpg">
                    <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="images/pic2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="beauty" style="width:auto;">
                </picture>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I did something like this, pretend it is a slider